# How to type "+" sign with xdotool automation utility?

Tags: x11, xdotool

How to type "+" sign with xdotool automation utility on Linux machines?

Answer (score 0):

Normally this is done using:

```
xdotool key plus
```

...however, if you have a Swedish keyboard you typically have a acute/grave accent button just left of the backspace key and in this case you can type an actual "+" character by running:

```
xdotool key shift+dead_acute
```

If can't figure out how to type "+", have a look at what key is just left of backspace in your localized keyboard and send the keycode for that to "xdotool key".